# I found this syntax for printing prime numbers and l am quite confused. I would like this community to clarify

Tags: python, function, range, integer-division

```
Nums = range(1,60)

def is_prime(Nums):
    for x in range(2, Nums):
        if (Nums%x) ==0:
            return False
    return True

prime_numbers = list(filter(is_prime,Nums))

Print(prime_numbers)
```

With the `for x in range(2, Nums)` syntax, l expect an error to be raised since the Nums argument is not an interger. How ever, python interprets it successfully and moves to the next line of code.

Again, what does the `if (Nums%x) ==0` syntax mean

Comment: The `Nums` in the function is scoped to that function: it's not the same as the global `Nums`. It's poor naming, because the value passed to the function is in fact a single int, not a range.

Comment: Why do you think the `Nums` argument isn't an integer? `filter()` calls the function with each element of the range as the argument.

Comment: Put `print(Nums)` inside the function to see what the value is.

Comment: `if (Nums%x) ==0` means "if the remainder when `Nums` is divided by `x` is zero".

Comment: It would be less confusing if you didn't use the same variable name for the function parameter and the global variable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused because the code snipped uses the same variable name for the function argument and the global variable.

The code can be interpreted as the following:

```
Nums = range(1,60)

def is_prime(n):
    print(n)
    for x in range(2, n):
        if (n%x) ==0:
            return False
    return True

prime_numbers = list(filter(is_prime,Nums))

print(prime_numbers)
```

You can also use the `type` function to see what is the type of the `Nums` argument (`n`) inside the function (it is an `integer`).

I recommend you to read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp) more about the `filter` function and if that is not sufficient, you can conduct further research on your own.

---

The expression `if (Nums%x) ==0`:

- `%` is the modulus operator in Python, which computes the remainder of the division of the number on its left (`Nums`) by the number on its right (`x`).
- `(Nums % x)` calculates the remainder when `Nums` is divided by `x`.
- `(Nums % x) == 0` checks if the remainder is equal to zero.

---

Additionally, I recommend learning more about naming conventions in Python, as they contribute to code readability and understandability

[Naming variables](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_variable_names.asp)